# Connecting the loopback-connector-rest api to a REST datasource

Tags: loopbackjs

I am looking for some clarification on using the loopback-connector-rest as I struggled to understand the documentation at: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/REST+connector

What I would like to do is take a request to **my REST API**, marshall incoming request body and then pass it onto another REST API.

I see that it is possible to create a function in code and call that from a hook on **my RESTAPI's** model object but was wondering if this is currently possible using a configuration file e.g.

Change the request to my API

```
{
   username: 'dan',
   file: 'A buffer with some data in it'
}
```

To a request to external API

```
{
  filename: 'buffer.txt',
  contents: 'A buffer with some data in it'
}
```

My understanding of the other connectors is that they **save** the resource passed to them and you can connect into that pipeline to 'marshall' data in the hooks but that the datasource handles the saving. However it looks more like the loopback-rest-connector is effectively to be used in one of the hooks to do the saving manually?  In which case what is it's use case as it seems that the request module is just as simple to use?

Thanks
Dan.

Comment: Can you clarify your question - maybe include some code if you're struggling with something specific? By using the built in Loopback REST connector rather than handrolling one using the `request` module you are using the same datasource paradigm. Here's an answer I gave to a similar question - upvote it if it is helpful :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/34153753/344022

Comment: Yep @conradj has the answer in that other question. To expand slightly, you would need to create a [custom remote method](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods) to accept the request **your** API receives and call the function generated by the REST datasource in order to marshall the data over to the other API.

Comment: Ah sorry for not being clear or posting code (I was trying to avoid writing code :P), the idea was that like the other datasources to use configuration rather than writing code but it is now clear this is not currently possible. @conradj thanks for the answer! jakerella, thanks that is as I suspected, great to have confirmation!

Comment: @DanielBruce no problem! I think you are overestimating the amount of custom code you would need to write though - a custom remote method or operation hook are really simple ways of extending the functionality of datasources.

Comment: Yeah, it's all working nicely (and live) by adding the remote method. Really enjoying loopback!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loopback Connector REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131073/loopback-connector-rest-api)