# Call another API from within an API

Tags: javascript, api, loopbackjs, strongloop

Probably the title doesn't explain what i want to achieve so i will try here.

I have an API (i am using Strongloop) through which i store some test results. Each test suite can vary in number of test cases, but at the end of a test suite, after the final result is posted, i want my API to send an OK/NOK status to another REST API.

I have a model named jobs and within this model, one key is a relation to another model, named reports, in which i save all the test results. The jobs model has only general data about the app.

My problem is that i don't know where to put the code for automatically sending the OK/NOK to the other API, after a test suite is done.

Can you advise me, please?

Comment: You can use the Loopback REST connector. Here's an answer I gave to a similar question - upvote it if it is helpful :-) stackoverflow.com/a/34153753/344022

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loopback Connector REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131073/loopback-connector-rest-api)

Comment: seems to be what i want. i will try it now and if it works i will upvote the solution. thanks!

Comment: If all you need to do is send a message to another API, the request library might be sufficient. No need to map out the other API as a datasource unless you're using it more extensively for back and forth communication. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the request module from Brian's reply and passed the modified property using ctx.instance.propertyName.

Thanks!